# change PHP compatibility from 7.4 to 8.0

Tags: php, php-8, php-7.4

I have a php script and need to make this code line compatible to php8.0:

```php
if ((is_array($key) && is_array($value)) || (strlen($key) > 0 && strlen($value) > 0)) {
```

I am not a programmer/coder. What I found out is, that the second part
(`strlen($key) > 0 && strlen($value) > 0`)  makes the error.
Because I get this error message in the application:

> Response: {"result":null,"error":{"code":0,"message":"strlen (): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, jtl\Connector\Model\Identity given","data":"Exception 'TypeError' (Code: 0) with message '**strlen(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, jtl\Connector\Model\Identity given**' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mod2060\jtlconnector\vendor\ jtl\connector\src\Core\Database\Mysql.php:567 "},"jtlrpc":"2.0","id":"unknown"}
> Exception bei category.push: strlen(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, jtl\Connector\Model\Identity given

I just changed PHP Version from 7.45 to 8.00 and get the error.
If I go back to PHP 7.45 it works fine again.

Comment: I would suggest making sure that the $value is a string before you try using strlen on it

Comment: Exactly as the error sais: `Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, jtl\Connector\Model\Identity given`

Comment: I don't think `strlen()` has ever worked with objects: https://3v4l.org/NhKjj - I suspect that you've been running PHP/7 with error reporting disabled, and only noticed when warning was promoted to fatal error. There's no way to fix this code if you don't understand what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is being thrown because either `$key` or `$value` is an object and not a string - the error message says it is an object of type 'jtl\Connector\Model\Identity'. So you would either need to modify that library and create a `__toString` [magic method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) function in it for that class, which defines how to convert that object to a string, or you might want to do an `is_object` check instead of (or before) using `strlen`.

[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the code as following:

`if ((is_array($key) && is_array($value)) || is_string($key) && is_string($value) && (strlen($key) > 0 && strlen($value) > 0)) {`